# Api Integration PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms, api, contact-form

I am stuck here. I would appreciate if someone would help me

I have the following code on a document from some guys in the Uk. That's their API integration instruction.

[Api intergration instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNTSg.jpg)

I have a landing page with a basic Contact form. the Form is in PHP. So I need to submit those leads into their custom CRM

this is my landing page https://bestmedicalaid.online/

This is the code on my contact form

```html
<?php
$email_type = 'html';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
//replace us3 with your actual datacenter
$submit_url = "https://ahbonitasqa.cagan.tech/api/public/leads/CreateLead";
$data = array(
    'email_address'=>$email,
    'name'=>$name,
    'surname'=>$surname,
    'mobile'=>$mobile,
    'email_type' => $email_type
);
$payload = json_encode($data);
 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));
 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if ($data->error){
    echo $data->error;
} else {
    echo "Your Email has been submited."; 
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention a specific problem. "I am stuck" doesn't give us any clue about what is going wrong when you try to run this code. Please provide some useful info, thanks.

Comment: P.S. why are you url-encoding JSON in the request body? That should not be necessary, and may be an issue.

Comment: Also, 2 of the fields in your $data array have names which don't match any of the fields mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: But I'm just guessing at things which don't look totally right...it's probably unproductive. you need to tell us something about your problem - do you get PHP errors? Or an unexpected response from the remote API? Give us a starting point to help you.

Comment: So the problem is that they are not receiving any leads on their end so I am not sure where I am getting this wrong and why is it that they are not getting the leads.

Comment: Ok. So what debugging have you done to investigate that? An obvious starting point is - what response do you get back from the API? (`var_dump($result);` is probably the most basic way of checking that. You can also use [curl_getinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get various useful bits of info about the response such as the HTTP status code.)

Comment: N.B. I'm fairly certain that `urlencode()` is not helping you - look at the mess it will make of your data: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b8087cb17682d20874594bd3319196b19498ac8 . JSON in the request body can be transmitted as-is - it's not part of the URL, so it doesn't need URL-encoding!

Comment: @ADyson I see what you mean by urlencode(). So I am going to try that and see what happens.  can only rely on this (var_dump($result); or from the Admin cos the actual developers who produced the document are hard to get hold of. Do think there is another way I could have written that contact form besides the way I have currently?

Comment: Well I can't see your contact form code (I'm not going to visit an external site - any code you want us to see should be _here_ in the question) so I can't comment on that. But apart from urlencode() (and the potential issue with mis-matching field names that I also mentioned earlier) there's nothing obviously amiss with the cURL code. Although it's a bit surprising that the API doesn't ask you for any kind of authentication - e.g. token or password or anything. Are you using something else like certificate auth or VPN or something outside the scope of the PHP code?

Comment: And what was the result of `var_dump($result);`, by the way?